# Maven & Netbeans - web pages not shown

Tags: maven, web-applications, netbeans

I have a maven web application (using Netbeans) and I have some web pages in ${basedir}/src/main/webapp but I am not able to see them in the Netbeans project explorer, although they exist on disk and they are displayed on browser after deployment. How do I have to configure Netbeans (or maybe some POM settings) in order to view the web pages?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Might be some folders are hidden in projects folder settings. Check it out... There is nothing to do with pom.xml on this issue.

Comment: There are no hidden folders.

Comment: Hidden in sens it is not included. Include the wedapp folder in the workspace.

Comment: The webapp is included in the workspace. However, if I need to modify any file under the WEB-INF directory I have to browse for it manually.